# Могу ли я игнорировать разрешения с соотношением сторон 1.3 - это допустимо для типовой игры?

Tags: unity3d

Вот список типовых разрешений и соотношений сторон.

- 640x480 1.3
- 800x600 1.3
- 1280x720 1.7
- 1366x678 2,014
- 1600x900 1.7
- 1920x1080 1.7
- 2160x1080 2
- 2560x1440 1.7
- 2960x1440 2,055
- 3200x1800 1.7
- 3840x2160 1.7

Из за особенностей игры, мой уровень должен быть прямоугольным.
Размер камеры на любых разрешениях одинаковый - 5 юнитов изменять его не надо.

Соотношение сторон 1.3, в моем случае, дает некрасивый результат. Мало места по горизонтали.
Соотношение сторон 1.7 (и всё что больше) дает желаемый результат.

**Могу ли я игнорировать разрешения с соотношением сторон 1.3 т.к. это 640x480 и 800x600 и в играх они не используются?**

Это нормально выпускать игру работающую только на разрешениях указанных выше, без 640x480 и 800x600?

Comment: Моё любимое разрешение 1600 на 1200 (именно из-за более квадратности), но мой старый монитор уже сломался, а новый с таким же разрешением я купить не смог, пришлось брать 1920 на 1080.  Так что наверное уже всё равно, поддерживаете вы 4:3 или нет.  Кстати, посмотрите на ноутбучные разрешения, там много нестандартных, и их лучше поддерживать.  А в чём проблема просто нарисовать на игровом экране полосы сверху и снизу, чтобы подогнать пропорции прямоугольника к нужным?  При таком подходе никто не уйдёт обиженным.

Comment: Нормально сделанная игра должна работать на ЛЮБОМ разрешении. В самом крайнем случае, если прям совсем нет идей как сделать нормальную адаптивность, можно тупо нарисовать чёрные полосы по краям

Answer (score 1):

**Соотношение (Aspect Ratio) не обозначается делением ширины на высоту! Соотношение должно быть дробью целых чисел!**

- То что ты вероломно обозвал 1.3, которое на самом деле 1.3(3), именуется соотношением "четыре к трем" (`4:3`).
- 1.7, которая на самом деле 1.7(7), без иррационального периуда тоже не обошлось, это `16:9`!

---

- `[3:2]` соотношение старых телевизоров.
- `[4:3]` `640x480`, `800x600` это соотношение старых мониторов для ПК, которых нет в продаже уже более десятилетия.
- `[16:9]` это соотношение используется в телевизоре, мониторах и телефонов в основном вышедших до IPhoneX.
- `~[2:1]` `1366x678`, `2960x1440` этот чисто эпплвский прикол используемый только для смартфонов.
- `[16:10]`/`[16:9]`/`[3:2]` это ноутбуки, причем современные, есть ещё множество старых.

---

В рамках конкретного соотношения, разрешения обозначаются только высотой в пикселях. Например для `16:9` это `1440p`(`2560x1440`), `1080p`, `720p` и т.д. которые можно встретить на <kbd>YouTube</kbd> выбирая качество видео.

---

По твоему списку ваще не понятно на что игра. Чё надо то? Суп от мух отдели! Судя по тому что есть выбор разрешения, это для ПК... но тогда что тут делает `~2:1`?

Но вообще контент игры должны адаптироваться к соотношениям сторон.